# Task "default" not found

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, syntax-error, task

I know there are similar questions posted here, but none of them have helped me figure out what's wrong. When I run grunt in my cmd (I'm on Windows 10) I get this message:

Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> >     Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue

I feel like I've been over my code with a finetooth comb, but I can't see the problem. Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
//Config
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    uglify: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                beautify: true,
                mangle: false,
                compress: false,
                preserveComments: 'all'
            },
            src: 'src/js/*.js',
            dest: 'js/script.min.js'
        },
        build: {
            src: 'src/js/*.js',
            dest: 'js/script.min.js'
        }
    },

    sass: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                outputstyle: 'expanded'
            },
            files:{
                'css/style.css': 'src/scss/style.scss'
            }
        },
        build: {
            options: {
                outputstyle: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'css/style.css': 'src/scss/style.scss'
            }
        }
    },

    postcss: {
        options: {
            map: false,
            processors: [
                require('pixrem')(),
                require('autoprefixer')({browsers: 'last 2 versions'}),
                require('cssnano')()
            ]
        }
        build: {
            src: 'css/*.css'
        }
    },

    watch: {
        js: {
            files: ['src/js/*.js'],
            tasks: ['uglify:dev']
        },
        sass:{
            files: ['src/scss/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass:dev']
        }
    }
});

//Load
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

//Register
grunt.registerTask('default', ["uglify:dev", "sass:dev"]);
grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify:build', 'sass:build', 'postcss:build']);
```

};

Comment: You are missing a comma after the `options` object in the `postcss` task.

Comment: Thank you!! That solved the problem!